# get multiple table result of SQL Server in R

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am using RODBC to query data from SQL SERVER.
How can I get both tables when the result contains two tables?

Currently my code is as follow

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=xxxx;atabase=xx;uid=xx;pwd=xxx")
initdata<- sqlQuery(channel,paste("select * from roles;select * from seat"))
odbcClose(channel)
```

The initdata contains result only from table roles

In fact, my query is a stored procedure like "exec XXX" and the stored procedure returns multiple tables. I wonder if there is a way to get all the result tables.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use 2 results or dataframes?

dataframes:

```
initroles <- sqlFetch(channel, "roles")
initseats <- sqlFetch(channel, "seat")
```

resultsets:

```
initroles <- sqlQuery(channel, "select * from roles")
initseats <- sqlQuery(channel, "select * from seat")
```

Comment: In fact, my query is a stored procedure like "exec XXX" and the stored procedure returns multiple tables. I wonder if there is a way to get all the result tables.

Comment: ok this would be good to know from the beginning ;) could you please edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

My syntax might be a little off, but I would try

```
SELECT * FROM roles JOIN seat ON roles.id = seat.id
```

Where `roles.id` and `seat.id` are the ID variables that link roles and seat.

Comment: There is no such relation between tables. In fact, my query is a stored procedure like "exec XXX" and the stored procedure returns multiple tables. I wonder if there is a way to get all the result tables.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what output you're looking for.  Sorry.